# Meaning of "original" in "By 'insolent,' not 'condolent,' as Anthony Wood quotes, Puttenham meant original."?

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary

On Vocabulary.com, I've found the following sentence for the entry "condolent":

> By 'insolent,' not 'condolent,' as Anthony Wood quotes, Puttenham meant original.

I don't know fore sure what "original" means here since paring every sense of both words, I still find it sounds unnatural to relate "insolent" to "original" in all cases.

Comment: "Condolent" is an incredibly rare word and not one you should ever use. "Condolent" is so rare there aren't many usage examples online, but that's certainly not a helpful one. Vocabulary.com isn't a particularly good source, and its usage examples are automatically generated, not selected to be useful. If possible, consult the OED via your library, which has better examples. ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condolent), probably the best free dictionary, has one example, which is better than vocabulary.com's.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quoted text,  from William Stebbing's *Sir Walter Ralegh* [sic] (1891) alleges:

(1) Anthony Wood [1632-1695] wrongly quoted [George] Puttenham as writing of Ralegh/Raleigh's 'lofty, condolent, and passionate' poetic vein;

(2) that what Puttenham actually wrote was 'lofty, insolent, and passionate';

(3) that 'insolent' in that era meant 'original' It might have helped if that word also had quote marks.

[*Walter Ralegh* (Stebbing, 1891, at Project Gutenberg)](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/25029/25029-h/25029-h.htm) 
(see start of page 77)

The Oxford English Dictionary gives *unaccustomed, unwonted, unusual, strange* as one meaning of 'insolent' from around the time that Puttenham wrote about Ralegh in *The Art of Poesie* (1589). One can see how Stebbing felt able to use 'original' as an era-correct meaning.

The correct modern spelling of Sir Walter Ralegh's surname is a matter of some debate: academics and literary folk may prefer 'Ralegh', but in popular culture an 'i' has crept in.

Comment: Even today, "original" can be used as a euphemism for all kinds of strange things (particularly in the arts), which could include the offensive or insulting as well as the baffling or incomprehensible. I think there may be a kind of joke intended.